# Creating a graph from distance matrix with a threshold

Tags: python, networkx, distance

I have calculated Jaccard distance matrix between my observations and got a diagonal distance matrix.
How can I generate a graph (netowrkx graph) in which there is an edge between two nodes (observations) if and only if the Jaccard distance is above 0.5

For example if i have the following distance matrix :

```
    A,   B,   C
 A  1    0.4  0.7
 B  0.4  1    0.6
 C  0.7  0.6  1
```

I will get a graph in which A are connected to C but not to B
,B are connected to C , and C are connected to A and B

Comment: What is your question ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust How can I generate a graph (netowrkx graph) in which there is an edge between two nodes (observations) if and only if the Jaccard distance is above 0.5

Comment: Mh, presumably the same way that you create any graph in NetworkX, but without supplying edges with a low distance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out NetworkX library's `from_numpy_array()`
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_array.html

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


weights = np.array([[1, 0.4 , 0.7], [0.4, 1, 0.6], [0.7, 0.6, 1]])

weights[weights < 0.5] = 0


G = nx.from_numpy_array(weights)


def draw_graph(G):
    pos = nx.planar_layout(G)
    default_axes = plt.axes(frameon=True)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos, node_size=1000, alpha=0.8, ax=default_axes)
    edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")
    for key,value in pos.items():
        pos[key] = np.array([value[0], value[1]+0.12])
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos = pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)


draw_graph(G)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , but how I remove edges with weights less than 0.5 ?

Comment: Updated my answer to the post. 
To answer your question, only non-zero values are considered as edges. So, use `np.where` to make the values zero which are below `0.5`